# Reset password field in a form for all user by adminstrator

Tags: php, drupal-7

In my drupal 7 project, one form contains one password field(not user's login password). The password is same for all the user. I observed the DB contains different values for different user in password field, but the user getting the proper password value when accessing. I want to reset the password field by the admin for all user in single shot. Could you please suggest me how can we do it programatically ?

Comment: So there is a form, with username and password, where the password is already set and cant be changed or what? please tell me why all users should have the same password, why do you then even need a password? and second, do I understand you correct, that you want to change the password for all users IN your database? which database do you use?

Comment: i dont know much about drupal, but you say "the password is same for all the user" and then you say "i observed the db contains different passwords".. that would mean you just think the password is the same, but drupal hashes it with some userkeys ore something.. otherwise the password should also be the same in each row..

Comment: all user save one machine's password. If I want to change the machine password then I need to reset same field for all the users.

Comment: yes then you could do that with an mysql(or whatever database you use)-query.. but as you said the password in the database is not the same foreach user, it will cause problems..